# Angular $http bad request

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Below I've got a function that should make a post to the server.

```
  var updateApplicationMetadata = function(appId, editorVersion, previewPubFile){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var result = $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '../resource/applications/'+appId,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: {
                editorVersion: editorVersion,
                previewPubFile: previewPubFile
            }
        });
        result.then(function(data){
            deferred.result(data);
            console.log('from services: ');
            console.log(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;

        };
```

I call this function like:

```
$scope.update = function(){
        MessageBus.emitMsg('notification','Application updates successful.');
        console.log('from update: ');
        console.log($scope.application.appId);
        console.log($scope.application.editorVersion);
        console.log($scope.application.previewPubFile);
        DataContext.updateApplicationMetaData($scope.application.appId,$scope.application.editorVersion ,$scope.application.previewPubFile);
    };
```

All of the values sent to the updateApplicationMetaData are valid.  I can use the rest client POST man and I can make the post work.  When I do it in angular, however, I get a bad request.  The URL and header content type are right, but I'm not sure about the data object.  It must be malformed.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an error in your code. You have:

```
deferred.result(data);
```

and it should be:

```
deferred.resolve(data);
```

for it to work. Also, you need to pass `'application/json'` as your accepts type for your data to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the $q service from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q I don't see a result method.  Perhaps change:

```
deferred.result(data);
```

To

```
deferred.resolve(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using ngResource for rest style json requests

[Angular resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)